# Can I increase lookup speed by positioning properties in object?

Tags: javascript, performance, lookup

I've seen a lot of questions about the fastest way to access object properties (like using . vs []), but can't seem to find whether it's faster to retrieve object properties that are declared higher than others in object literal syntax.

I'm working with an object that could contain up to 40,000 properties, each of which is an `Array` of length 2. I'm using it as a lookup by value.

I know that maybe 5% of the properties will be the ones I need to retrieve most often. Is either of the following worth doing for increased performance (decreased lookup time)?

1. Set the most commonly needed properties at the top of the object literal syntax?
2. If #1 has no effect, should I create two separate objects, one with the most common 5% of properties, search that one first, then if the property isn't found there, then look through the object with all the less-common properties?

Or, is there a better way?

Comment: Although I'm not 100% sure, I believe it wouldn't change performance because objects don't really have an 'order' per se like an array does. Object lookup, unlike Arrays, are in constant time. However, like I said I'm not sure so I'm also looking forward to a more clear answer. Great question.

Comment: I agree with @TylerMcGinnis - great question! I also dig your second approach. That's smart!

Comment: i would make two objects with 40,000 keys each so that you don't have to search sub-arrays to find your data. can you show us a data example so that we might be sure?

Comment: @dandavis, when I look up using the key value, I want the whole array. There's no need to search the sub-arrays.

Comment: then i'm not sure i understand what your're "searching"; can you chow us an example of the data? do you not know the name of the key? Property access in V8 is near instant...

Comment: I think approach #2 might come with quite a performance penalty when looking up one of those 95% less often needed properties – I fear the necessary if/else logic might be quite a lot slower than the lookup itself (which should be highly optimized internally by the JS engine already) – so it will likely depend on the actual use case. Disclaimer: This is “gut feeling”, I have no evidence to back this up.

Answer (score 3):

I did a js perf here: http://jsperf.com/object-lookup-perf

I basically injected 40000 props with random keys into an object, saved the "first" and "last" keys and looked them up in different tests. I was surprised by the result, because accessing the first was 35% slower than accessing the last entry.

Also, having an object of 5 or 40000 entries didn’t make any noticeable difference.

The test case can most likely be improved and I probably missed something, but there is a start for you.

**Note:** I only tested chrome

Comment: Really interesting results. I'm getting 48-49% slower accessing the first property than the last, also using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something like "indexOf" searches front to back, so placing common items higher in the list will return them faster. Most "basic" search algorithms are basic top down (simple sort) searches. At least for arrays.

Comment: But doesn't indexOf search array indexes, while the question is talking about Objects? There's no question indexOf is slower. http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-object-lookup/4

Comment: I'm not using an array for this because the key values aren't sequential numbers. The lookup is an Object.

Comment: Oh, whoops! So you're just accessing properties of an object directly? I found this article, I don't know a lot about it: http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/closure-vs-object-performance.html

I would say that you should probably break that object into more manageable ones if at all possible. You can hit a stackoverflow if it lags long enough (although usually reserved for infinite loops).

Answer (score 1):

> Set the most commonly needed properties at the top of the object literal syntax?

No. Choose readability over performance. If you've got few enough properties that you use a literal in the code, it won't matter anyway; and you should order the properties in a logical sequence.

Property lookup in objects is usually based on hash maps, and position should not make a substantial difference. Depending on the implementation of the hash, they might be neglible slower, but I'd guess this is quite random and depends heavily on the applied optimisations. It should not matter.

> If #1 has no effect, should I create two separate objects, one with the most common 5% of properties, search that one first, then if the property isn't found there, then look through the object with all the less-common properties?

Yes. If you've got really huge objects (with thousands of properties), this is a good idea. Depending on the used data structure, the size of the object might influence the lookup time, so if you've got a smaller object for the more frequent properties it should be faster. It's possible that different structures are chosen for the two objects, which could perform better than the single one - especially if you know beforehand in which object to look. However you will need to test this hypothesis with your actual data, and you should beware of [premature [micro-]optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization).

Answer (score 1):

If you have so many properties, they must be computed, no ? So you can replace the (string, most probably) computation by an integer hash computation, then use this hash in a regular array.
You might even use one single array by putting values in the 2*ith, 2*i+1th slot.
If you can use a typed array here, do it and you could no go faster.

Comment: Interesting idea, do you happen to have sample code?